# PySpark java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using local windows and trying to load the `XML` file with the following code on python, and i am having this error, do anyone knows how to resolve it,

this is the code

```python
df1 = sqlContext.read.format("xml").options(rowTag="IRS990EZ").load("https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201611339349202661_public.xml")
```

and this is the error

```python
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4832eb48a4aa> in <module>()
----> 1 df1 = sqlContext.read.format("xml").options(rowTag="IRS990EZ").load("https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201611339349202661_public.xml")

C:\SPARK_HOME\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    157         self.options(**options)
    158         if isinstance(path, basestring):
--> 159             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    160         elif path is not None:
    161             if type(path) != list:

C:\SPARK_HOME\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\SPARK_HOME\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\SPARK_HOME\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.load.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:469)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$newAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$newAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:1148)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:1148)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XmlFile$.withCharset(XmlFile.scala:46)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(XmlRelation.scala:47)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(XmlRelation.scala:46)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation.<init>(XmlRelation.scala:45)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:65)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Answer not useful?

Comment: nop that was not I got it in different way, I will post the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow pyspark is unable to load the http or https, one of my colleague found the answer for this so here is the solution,

before creating the spark context and sql context we need to load this two line of code

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.4.1 pyspark-shell'
```

after creating the sparkcontext and sqlcontext from `sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate` and `sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)`

add the http or https url into the sc by using `sc.addFile(url)`

```
Data_XMLFile = sqlContext.read.format("xml").options(rowTag="anytaghere").load(pyspark.SparkFiles.get("*_public.xml")).coalesce(10).cache()
```

this solution worked for me

Comment: You are correct - actually `addFile()` [can be used](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.addFile) with HTTP(S) & FTP, too! Nice catch (+1), but my solution would also work if you downloaded the file first (and the XML Package I linked included instructions for the usage of `--packages` flag in the command line, which I guessed you knew already).

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: you cannot use dataframe reader & `load` to access files on the web (`http` or `htpps`). I suggest you first download the file locally.

See the [`pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader` docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader) for more on the available sources (in general, local file system, HDFS, and databases via JDBC).

Irrelevantly to the error, notice that you seem to use the `format` part of the command incorrectly: assuming that you use the [XML Data Source for Apache Spark package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml), the correct usage should be `format('com.databricks.spark.xml')` (see the [example](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#python-api)).

Answer (score 0):

I've commit a similar but slightly different error: forgot the "s3://" prefix to file path. After adding this prefix to form "s3://path/to/object" the following code works:

```
my_data = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
               .option("header", "true")\
               .option("inferSchema", "true")\
               .option("delimiter", ",")\
               .load("s3://path/to/object")
```

Comment: that's for the CSV, but in case of XML this format was giving some error.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a similar issue with the CSV file basically we were trying to load a CSV file into spark.

We were able to load the file successfully by making use of the pandas' library, first we loaded the file into the pandas data frame, and then by using the pandas we were able to load the data into the spark data frame.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('appName').getOrCreate()
pdf = pd.read_csv('file patth with https')
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```